# OpenSUSE 13.1 java jar exception : java.awt.HeadlessException : No X11 DISPLAY variable was set

Tags: java, swing, x11, opensuse

I have a runnable java jar which is working fine in Windows. The same jar I am trying to run on OpenSUSE 13.1 but it throws the
    java.awt.HeadlessException : No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

I tried almost all possible options (like `export $DISPLAY=:0` and so on) available on Google and StackOverFlow but still with the exception.

**Below are the OS-Release details :**

```
NAME=openSUSE;
VERSION="13.1 (Bottle)";
VERSION_ID="13.1";
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE 13.1 (Bottle) (x86_64)";
ID=opensuse;
ANSI_COLOR="0;32";
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:opensuse:opensuse:13.1";
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.opensuse.org";
HOME_URL="https://opensuse.org/";
ID_LIKE="suse";

Even small help is appreciated.
```

Comment: I know you may have checked this, but I would ask that you have a working gui desktop on this machine ?

Comment: @jr593 : yes, I am able to run other Swing application java jar on the same desktop with the GUI.

Comment: I vaguely recall having to switch from kde to gnome.

Comment: do I need to use JPanel instead of JFrame to solve this exception? Is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: The issue got solved. For this I was supposed to do three steps :
Step 1 : in VM Options added the line ' -Djava.awt.headless=false' 
Step 2 : added static block   
static {       
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
        System.out.println(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless());       
    } 
in the java code. 
Step 3 : In Opensuse 'edit etc/sysconfig/displaymanager' set DISPLAYMANAGER as "kdm" (you can set any Non-Headless Window Manager)